# Hyper-V Ubuntu 10.04, Filesystem suddenly becomes Read-Only?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, hyper-v, read-only

We are running a Ubuntu 10.04 VM  on a Hyper-V system,
The VM is dedicated to running one of our web applications.

We have enabled the Hyper-V drivers in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` like so:

```
hv_vmbus
hv_storvsc
hv_blkvsc
hv_netvsc
```

And updated the kernel image like so:

```
$ update-initramfs -u
```

And all was good... until..

This morning i got a support request that our web application was throwing an error 500, so i checked the logs and nothing was there.

Then I remembered that I had seen this on another of our ubuntu servers so I...

```
$ touch foo.txt
```

And my suspicions were confirmed:

```
touch:  cannot touch `foo.txt':  Read-only file system
```

Why is the filesystem randomly becoming readonly?

Is this only in Ubuntu on HV? Is it a problem on RedHat or Cent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the log?  Most likely the filesystem had errors, and went into read-only state because of it.

(Assuming you're using ext3 or ext4, as are Ubuntu's defaults:) You can adjust this behavior with the `errors` mount option.

`errors=remount-ro` is the default; `errors=continue` (to stay read-write at your own peril) and `errors=panic` (stop, drop, and <strike>roll</strike> crash) are your other options.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Hyper-V  issue , hosts running Red Hat or Centos will have the same problems

Comment: On what do you base this conclusion? Supporting documentation would be very helpful.